# fetch random unique records from table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch 50 random records without duplication.

```
Table Name : table 1
Fields : test_id,test_name,test_phone.
```

Can anyone suggests me query that can fetch 50 random records from database without duplication?

Comment: Cant you try some stored procedure for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50;
```

Do make sure that they're unique, make sure that `test_id` is an auto-increment `INT`.

Comment: may I know why test_id must be auto increment? we are not passing test_id in query any where..

Comment: Because auto-increment will ensure that the row is unique every time. I guess I should ask, what do you mean by "duplication"?

Comment: will it run properly if my test_id is not primary key and not set to auto increment? I got proper answer for my current issue  but for sake of my knowledge I am asking..

Comment: It will run, it just won't be unique. I've altered my answer to include the `DISTINCT` keyword, as @Ampere suggested.

Answer (score 1):

use the following query

```
SELECT distinct * FROM `table_1` order by rand() limit 50
```

it works.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50
```

Contact if you have any doubt.

Comment: While this will return 50 records, they won't be random.

Comment: Ok it should be ordered by rand() to return random records.